# How to design if the crystal report contains so many fields in details section?in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I designed an winforms application i got the data from back-end and also
  displayed that data in crystal report everything is fine but my table contains
  nearly 35 fields then i will select all my fields then crystal report is
  not shown the data clearly something like if an id is there in that column it 
  will display # sign like that.

If the column contains name ex: Anil it shows an only like that. I know the
  report contains more fields that's why it shown like that.

If i select only 5 fields in my report then report shown nice. But if the 
  fields more then how to arrange so many fields in details section? I am new
  to crystal report Please give your suggestion/advice thanks.

Comment: Maybe have a look here. Looks like a similar issue. [Crystal Reports displays #### in numeric fields after upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876403/crystal-reports-displays-in-numeric-fields-after-upgrade)

Comment: @TKelly yeah but i got the data perfectly. my issue here is i want to display 34 column in my crystal report. Is there any way to extend crystal report row size( Details section) or any other way to display all the columns in a first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the size of the report to accomodate all fields in detail section.

Go to `File ---> Page Setup ---> remove default values and provide your values.`

This will increase the report space and you can place the fields as required.

Regarding `#` issue... since there is no sufficient space number will be displayed as `####`.

Comment: Where is the file option in crystal report?can you tell me?I found in visual studion file--->pagesetup. But pagesetup in visualstudio that option is disabled.

Comment: i found in crystal report tab-->design --> pagesetup -->yes we can provide our own values. but when i go for print is there any problem?for extend pagesetup values? Thanks

Comment: O actually i don't know how to export our crystal report to excel?can you give me your guideline for this?Actually i generated this report as crystal report. I think can i write additional code for that? thanks.

Comment: You may need to....but in crystal reports you have option to export in different options

Comment: ok can you tell me one option for export into excel?using crystal report?means if we have any wizard then can you please tell?Thanks

Comment: Are you able to see export button??

Comment: No i didn't that's why i am asking and one more in pagesetup there is an option no print if i checked that one in page option it will give A4Sheets and so on..If i use that option is there any problem for print the report?

Comment: no not in that.. can you paste the screen shot of the design

Comment: yeah.but the design is normal i am not extend the report up to now. You already said that how to expend i tried also it will extended. But after extend the report page. How to export report to excel that's what i am asking. Thanks.

Comment: Thats what i am saying..there will be icon that will show you different export options...are you able to see that icon

Comment: Ok can you tell me that icon location?where it exactly?

Comment: Yes siva i found an icon "Export Report" it is in main report preview tab i found this. It will export report in excel (not only this so many options are there) but it is not stored the data in excel format it will store just like word pad format. why?Thanks.

Comment: yes i used the option dat is right before saving i set microsoftexcel option. but it doesn't save in excel insted just like word pad.